# How to update a ML model during a spark streaming job without restarting the application?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming

I've got a Spark Streaming job whose goal is to :

- read a batch of messages
- predict a variable Y given these messages using a pre-trained ML pipeline

The problem is, I'd like to be able to **update** the model used by the executors without restarting the application.

Simply put, here's what it looks like :

```
model = #model initialization

def preprocess(keyValueList):
    #do some preprocessing

def predict(preprocessedRDD):
    if not preprocessedRDD.isEmpty():
        df = #create df from rdd
        df = model.transform(df)
        #more things to do

stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [kafkaTopic], kafkaParams)

stream.mapPartitions(preprocess).foreachRDD(predict)
```

In this case, the model is simply used. Not updated.

I've thought about several possibilities but I have now crossed them all out :

- broadcasting the model everytime it changes (cannot update it, read-only)
- reading the model from HDFS on the executors (it needs the SparkContext so not possible)

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: which ML algorithm are you using? There are a couple of streaming-oriented algorithms in Spark. I'm guessing you've ruled those out, but thought I'd mention just in case.

Comment: hi, for the moment we're thinking about using Word2Vec to build features. We did not choose a model yet, it has to be flexible.

Comment: In that case, I would build a REST API using Flask that exposes calls for train, update and predict that you call via HTTP requests from your `predict(preprocessedRDD)` function. Decoupling like that would give you greater flexibility in the model you choose, how often it is updated, where it is stored and how you upgrade the code of both model and streaming job.

Comment: The model runs on a Spark cluster not on a standalone REST application. How could that work ?

Comment: Use separate Spark jobs, one for streaming, one for managing the model. The trouble is you haven't selected a model yet, not all of the Spark models support saving/loading, not all of them support streaming updates, and we haven't even gotten into the operational complexity of handling failures, restarts and code changes in your streaming job. By separating the model job from the streaming job you buy yourself a lot more flexibility. You're at the bleeding edge here I'm afraid, it's not a solved problem in my experience.

Comment: Even if I use another Spark application to manage the model I don't see how I could "update" the model used by the executors in the "prediction application". Either it's a variable serialized by the driver or it's retrieved from somewhere in the foreachRDD when I process the messages. The thing is, how can I retrieve this model ? Even if this is managed by the other application the executors still have to go and get the updated model. And they don't have a sparkcontext to read from HDFS.

Comment: The function you pass to foreachRDD is executed by the driver, it's only the rdd operations themselves that are performed by executors, as such you don't need to serialize the model - assuming you are using a Spark ML pipeline which operates on RDD's, which as far as I know they all do. Spark handles the training/prediction for you, you don't need to manually distribute it.

Comment: Yes, there was a misunderstanding right here. I guess I'll be able to load the updated model and use it since it will be executed by the driver. Would you mind writing this as an answer ? I'll accept it as soon as I try it and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue before in two different ways:

- a TTL on the model
- rereading the model on each batch

Both those solutions suppose an additional job training on the data you've accumulated regularly (e.g. once a day).

Comment: I don't see the TTL mentioned anywhere on the broadcast documentation. Could you please provide a link ?
Moreover, are you the one downvoting ImDarrenG ? If so, care to explain ?

Comment: It's not part of the built-in API, it's something you'll have to implement yourself typically relying on an external configuration mechanism (like Zookeeper or Consul) where you'd store the time at which your model invalidates.

Comment: Also, I personally use `transform` to do batch predictions on each `RDD` and reserve `foreachRDD` for outputting my results. I downvoted since it doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: By the way you can access a `SparkContext`/`SparkSession` during a streaming `transform`/`foreachRDD`, cf https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/SqlNetworkWordCount.scala

Comment: You can access the context from transform/foreachrdd because it is executed on the driver - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd and as such there is no need to distribute the model to executors manually, that is handled by Spark - note in these examples that we are passing dataset to be transformed, we don't need to operate on individual data items  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#example-estimator-transformer-and-param

Comment: My badly worded point is, my answer renders the question moot and as such is relevant.

Answer (score -1):

The function you pass to foreachRDD is executed by the driver, it's only the rdd operations themselves that are performed by executors, as such you don't need to serialize the model - assuming you are using a Spark ML pipeline which operates on RDD's, which as far as I know they all do. Spark handles the training/prediction for you, you don't need to manually distribute it.